# How to replace space with a digit in middle of the mobile number

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with column name as "Mobile No".Few of the entries are having space in the 6th position which ends up 9 digit number.

Would like to replace space in 6th position with a digit(8) to make 10 digit number. please suggest.

Before applying below code have ensured, no 'NaN's in df["Mobile No"] column and code was run. After running its df["Mobile No"] filled with 'NaN's.
Looks like something isn't working.

```
df["Mobile No"] = df["Mobile No"].str.replace('  ', ' ')
Sample number with space in '88888 8888'
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample to question?

Comment: @jezrael have added sample data and edited my question accordingly,

Comment: What are you trying to do with `df["Mobile No"] = df["Mobile No"].str.replace('  ', ' ')`? If you want to replace all white space with a single space consider `df["Mobile No"] = df["Mobile No"].str.replace(r'\s', ' ')` but also, why not then `replace(' ', '8')`?

Comment: @Dan, I did try with `df["Mobile No"] = df["Mobile No"].str.replace(' ', '8 ')`.It worked. however, after applying to replace, am seeing a lot of records with filled 'NaN's which were not there before. What could be the reason?

Comment: You need to post example data, find a subset of say 3 or 4 numbers that reproduce that error and post those with your code (by editing your question)

Comment: @jezrael, I had to convert df["Mobile No"] to from Int to str and then call replace_by_index function for applying the space in a particular position. This conversion resulted in decimal value for the mobile numbers which did not have spaces. Ex ~9000018226.0~.So do we need to have another function which replaces the decimal value and dot? As replace_by_index function does n't work for Int-getting ints cannot be subscripted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need replace all emprt strings use `\s`:

```
#replace each space by value
df["Mobile No1"] = df["Mobile No"].str.replace(r'\s', '8')
#repalce consecutive spaces by one value
df["Mobile No2"] = df["Mobile No"].str.replace(r'\s+', '8')
```

If need replace empty space in some position:

```
def replace_by_index(text, pos, replacement):
        return ''.join(text[:pos-1] + replacement + text[pos:]) if text[pos-1] == ' ' else text

df['Mobile No3'] = df['Mobile No'].apply(lambda x: replace_by_index(x, 6, '8'))
print (df)
     Mobile No   Mobile No1  Mobile No2   Mobile No3
0   08881 2889   0888182889  0888182889   0888182889
1   0881 28889   0881828889  0881828889   0881 28889
2  0888881  29  08888818829  0888881829  0888881  29
```